# Passing a new header in Spring Interceptor

Tags: spring, interceptor

I want to add authentication logic to interceptor. When service is called, interceptor will authenticate. Once authenticated, I want to put a new header in the request say 'header-user': 'john-doe'. But in interceptor, I am unable to do that, when I add to response.setHeader(), nothing happens.
I want to use this new header in actual REST service.

```
public class AuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

  // Authenticate
  // Add header
   response.setHeader("header-user", "john-doe"); // not working

    return true;
  }
...
}
```

If I add Filter, filter is called before Interceptor.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out from [Using Spring Interceptor](https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-interceptors-your) that I can use setAttribute

```
request.setAttribute("user", "john-doe");
```

In controller side use,

```
public String testService(@RequestAttribute("user") String user){
```